# Problems compiling windows 64 program on linux - headers

Tags: c++, linux, gcc, header

I have been trying to compile a windows 64 program, MSVAR1.3, on linux and have had problems with Linux and the headers that the program calls.  The program calls for:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <math.h>
#ifdef __BORLANDC__
    #include <float.h>
```

If I run the compile (using gcc in linux) and try to use the -I flag to tell it where the headers are, it doesn't get any better than if I run the compilation without headers at all.  I have included some of the output below (I get almost 300 lines of unrecognized variables).

I have also tried running it with an -lm flag for the math library and this reduces the unrecognized errors, but if there are flags relating to libraries for the other headers, I haven't been able to find them.  PLEASE HELP!!!!

(Errors from running using the -I flag:)

```
gcc msvar1.3.c -o msvar1.3 -lm/tmp/ccpZIkC1.o: In function `main':
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x38): undefined reference to `opengfsr'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x927): undefined reference to `gfsr8'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x94c): undefined reference to `gfsr8'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x971): undefined reference to `gfsr8'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x9a2): undefined reference to `disrand'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x111a): undefined reference to `printerr'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x1809): undefined reference to `printerr'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x1ad2): undefined reference to `printerr'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x1be6): undefined reference to `gfsr8'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x2773): undefined reference to `closegfsr'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x2791): undefined reference to `closegfsr'
/tmp/ccpZIkC1.o: In function `treesummary':
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x2808): undefined reference to `printerr'
/tmp/ccpZIkC1.o: In function `read_params':
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x2b1f): undefined reference to `printerr'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x2b64): undefined reference to `printerr'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x2b72): undefined reference to `intrand'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x2bb7): undefined reference to `printerr'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x3000): undefined reference to `printerr'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x3063): undefined reference to `printerr'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x3077): undefined reference to `printerr'
/tmp/ccpZIkC1.o: In function `choosepar':
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x36fb): undefined reference to `gfsr8'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x374b): undefined reference to `gfsr4'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x3799): undefined reference to `gfsr4'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x37b8): undefined reference to `norm4'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x37e5): undefined reference to `gfsr4'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x3826): undefined reference to `norm4'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x3853): undefined reference to `gfsr4'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x3894): undefined reference to `norm4'
msvar1.3.c:(.text+0x38f7): undefined reference to `norm4'
```

Comment: You should not try to compile a Windows 64 program on Linux. You may want to *port* some code to Linux, and that often requires *changing* the source code. And you should compile with `gcc -Wall -g` and show us the code that you are compiling (not only the first few `#include` directives of it...)

Comment: I would be happy to post the program and the error messages if I could figure out how to attach files - both are too long to post either one.

Answer (score 2):

"undefined reference" errors are not from missing headers - they're linker errors indicating you don't link with an object, nor have a -l (minus ell) flag specifying a library, that exports these symbols.  The headers only constitute a promise that variables and out-of-lines function matching the header declarations will be found in an object/library you provide at link time - you're breaking that promise.

You need to either find the libraries containing those symbols, or find the source and compile them.

Comment: I did find the header files for each of the #include strings and tried to tell it where they were using an -I flag without success.  I had fewer errors when I ran it using the math library flag so I was hoping, rather desperately, that there might be equivalent libraries for each of the others but haven't really found a list of them anywhere.

Comment: @user3161904: a quick Google turned up some source code for a gfsr4 and norm4 functions - not sure if they do what you want: http://www.reading.ac.uk/Statistics/genetics/software/bayesfst/myutil.c (and .h)

Answer (score 0):

I compiled [msvar1.3](http://www.maths.bris.ac.uk/~mamab/stuff/) with command:

```
gcc -o msvar1.3 myutil.c msvar1.3.c -lm
```